# Wrapping inner contents with div not saving

Tags: simple-html-dom

I'm getting the HTML as follows:

```
$htmlA = file_get_html($u);
$contentA = $htmlA->find("#content",0);
```

Next, I'm wrapping that content with a div, class "cell":

```
$contentA->innertext = "<div class=\"cell\">".$contentA->innertext."</div>";
$htmlA->save();
```

When I echo $contentA, the wrapping div is present as expected.

But when I tried a "find" on the result, it won't find it - it just returns null.

```
$contentA->find('.cell', 0);
```

I then tried:

```
$contentA = str_get_html($contentA->find('.cell', 0));
```

I also tried:

```
$contentA = str_get_html($htmlA->find('.cell', 0));
```

But none of them find the div.cell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I should have obtained the html from the string $html, not including the find.

This worked:

```
$contentA = str_get_html($htmlA)->find('.cell', 0);
```